# Как раскодировать дату?

Tags: php, yii2

Разрабатываю приложение на yii2-advanced.

Закодировал дату в unix-формате и сохранил в базу данных, а раскодировать не могу, т.к. использую GridView и DetailView.

Как в них написать расшифровку?
GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at'

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

DetailView:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at'
    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
'created_at:datetime'
```

Либо вот так:

```
[
   'header'  => 'Создано',
   'content' => function ($model) {
         return Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->created_at, 'dd/MM/Y H:i');
          },
],
```

Comment: да, то что нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Либо сокращенный вариант `'created_at:datetime'`, либо более подробный

```
[
    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'format' => 'datetime', // time date ['date', 'php:Y-m-d']
],
```